# Php login system -null value logging in

Tags: php

My PHP login system with MYSQL is logging in with null values.  Why is this happening?

```
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "");
mysql_select_db("deirastaff");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' and password = '$password' ")

    or die("Login failed" .mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row['username']==$username && $row['password']==$password) {

   $_SESSION['username']=$username;

    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("staff.php","_self");</script>';

    //header("location:staff.php");

    //echo "Login Successfull "."Welcome ".$row['username'];    

}else {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert("Login failed!");
    window.open("index.php","_self");
    </script>';

    //header("location:index.php");
    //echo "Login Failed !";
    break;
}
```

Comment: You should use mysqli, not mysql as it is now deprecated, it is also wildly insecure. You should also use the mysqli_real_escape_string() function to prevent SQL injection. I.E. $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username'];

Comment: Format your code by adding four spaces before every line, then it will show up a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

MySQLi is better to use...

But if you want to use MySQL then try this code..

```
if(isset($submit)) //name of your submit button
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' and password = '$password' ") or die("Login failed" .mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)<1)
    {
        echo "Login Failed" ;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION[username]=$username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check you have values before conducting the query.

```
if (!empty($row['username']) && !empty($row['password'])) { ... }
```

Also you could set the username and password tables to not allow null values.